# Можно ли активировать скрипт AutoHotkey на ПК, не останавливая действия кнопок мыши?

Tags: скрипт, autohotkey, macro, ahk, ahk-script

Есть данный ahk скрипт. Для его активации выбрана правая кнопка мыши, но она только включает или выключает скрипт, когда он запущен. В системе/браузере/играх пкм не работает. Как сделать так, чтобы пкм и работала как обычно, и активировала скрипт?

```
Hotkey, RButton, CheckBox
Gui, Add, Text, xm ym+33, Speed:
Gui, Add, Edit, xm+40 ym+30 vSpeed w240 ,1
Gui, Add, Text, xm ym+63 , Timer (ms):
Gui, Add, Edit, xm+40 ym+60 vTimer w240
Gui, Add, CheckBox, xm+200 ym+97 vED gCheckBox, Toggle Script
Gui, Add, Button, xm ym+90 w100 gButtonApplyChanges , Apply Changes
Gui, Show

Hotkey, LButton Up , LeftButtonUp , Off
Hotkey , LButton , LeftButton , Off
Return

GuiClose:
ExitApp

LeftButton:
    Gui , Submit , NoHide
    SendInput , {LButton Down}
    SetTimer , DragDown , % 10 / Speed
    SetTimer , StopDragDown , % Timer
Return

LeftButtonUp:
    SendInput , {LButton Up}
    SetTimer , DragDown , Off
Return

DragDown:
    Gui , Submit , NoHide
    DllCall("mouse_event" , "UInt" , 0x01 , "UInt" , 0 , "UInt" , 1 + Speed)
Return

StopDragDown:
    SetTimer , DragDown , Off
Return

CheckBox:
    Gui , Submit , NoHide
    If (A_ThisHotkey = "RButton")
        GuiControl,, ED,% !ED
    Gui , Submit , NoHide
    Stat := (ED) ? "On" : "Off"
    Hotkey,LButton,% Stat
    Hotkey,LButton Up,% Stat
Return

ButtonApplyChanges:
    Gui , Submit,NoHide
    If (HotkeyC != HotkeyCC) {
        Hotkey,% HotkeyCC := HotkeyC,% CheckBox,% On
        Hotkey,% HotkeyCC,% CheckBox,% Off
    }
Return
```